# Is it possible to ignore an exception in AWS lambda to be added to the "Errors" metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

My issue is as follows - I have a lambda function attached to API gateway, where i map some error codes using integration response.

The thing is, i can only map errors if the lambda function fails (throws an exception).

This makes the "Errors" metric kick in - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-invocation

We monitor this metric, and we get now email alerts also there's an exception for invalid input, or something else that is fixable by the user (and should not trigger an error metric).

Is there any way to ignore certain errors from being written as an error metric?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, if you know exactly which kinds of errors you want to ignore, you should use `try ... except` blocks (or equivalent, depending on which language you use) in your lambda targeting those specific errors.

This way you can initiate graceful exit without failing lambda execution.

Comment: That means that the lambda will return 200 code - which is pretty bad for the API consumers, no? If i could control the status code that is returned, i'd return a regular json instead of an exception.

Comment: In that case I don't think you can have it both ways. You should treat all errors as errors and instead tweak your monitoring, create metric which will parse error type and suppress some of them from being sent out.

Comment: That means i need to catch all exceptions, and miss the ones outside of my code (lambda invocation errors that are not related directly to my code, etc..)

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: Basically have metrics for all possible exceptions, except some selected ones.
sadly i guess i'll go with the custom direction, catching everything and not using the AWS error metrics.
Thanks.